# Suming in Pandas after and before nth rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and learning Pandas. I have a data set given below, need to sum all the row in the Amount column before the first GPS product purchased and do the same after the first GPS product purchased till the second GPS purchase.

Here's the data set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({Product : [Sub,Sub,Sub,Sub,GPS,Sub,Sub,GPS,Sub,Sub]} {Amount :[13,15,25,32,43,76,23,45,67,89]})
```

Thank You for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use iloc indexing:

```
# locate first ocurence of purchase
first_GPS_index = df[df['Product']==GPS].index.min()
# use iloc to index same way as you would in python list
sum_until = df.iloc[:first_GPS_index].sum()
sum_after = df.iloc[first_GPS_index+1:].sum()
```